# Can $1/\log(2)$ be represented as a period?

Tags: number-theory, definite-integrals

In [this](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kontzagi.pdf) article by Zagier-Kontsevich, *period* is defined as values of integral of a rational function over a domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ defined by polynomial inequalities with rational coefficients. For example, $\pi, \log(2), \zeta(3)$ are periods, and $e$ is conjecturally not a period. The set of periods form a ring (period ring), which is not a field. My question is: is 
$$
\frac{1}{\log(2)}
$$
also a period? More generally, how about
$$
\frac{1}{\log\alpha}
$$
for $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$? Note that $\log\alpha$ is a period for $\alpha\in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. I tried to find integral representations of $1/\log(x)$, but I can't find a suitable one. Also, if it is not, it would be super hard to prove that it is actually not a period.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213659/following-the-definition-of-kontsevich-and-zagier-is-it-known-if-conjecturally?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Does that "heuristic" implies that $1/\log 2$ might not be a period?