# Rational integral representation of inverse logarithm.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $x\in(0,1)$. Let $p_i(x,z)$ generically denote a sequence of multivariate polynomials in $(x,z)$.

Is it possible to write:

$$\frac{1}{\ln(x)} = \int_0^1\frac{p_2(x,z)}{p_3(x,z)}dz?$$

I know for example that:

$$\ln(x) = \int_0^1\frac{(1-x)dz}{1-(1-x)z},$$

but unfortunately I don't know a trick for the inverse logarithm (maybe it doesn't even exist). The only one I know is:

$$\frac{1}{\ln(x)}=\frac{1}{x-1}\int_0^1 x^tdt,$$

which isn't in the right form.

Note that I'm willing to allow multiple integrals, e.g. another example:

$$\ln^2(x)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^2dwdz}{(1-(1-x)w)(1-(1-x)z)}$$

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^t dt = \color{red}{-}\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$, not just $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$

Comment: I think a problem arises with the algebraic properties of $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$.In particular, it has a simple pole at x=1, and once that pole is removed via the denominator of the integral, it has a zero at 0 which an integral of a rational polynomial is probably barred from. Without proof, it is reasonable to suppose that we have to get rid of the pole at x=1 via $q(x,z)=(1-x)r(x,z)$, where $q$ is the denominator polynomial. But this gives us $\frac{1-x}{\log(x)}$, which approaches $0$ as $x\to 0^+$ very quickly, likely too quickly for such a rational integral to satisfy.

Comment: Perhaps useful, even though it is not what you look for : from Taylor's formula with integral remainder (to the function $1/\log$), one has, for $0<x<1$ : $$\frac{1}{\log(x)}=\int_0^x\frac{t-x}{t\log^2(t)}\text{d}t,$$ which can be turned into an integral on $[0,1]$ *via* a linear change of variable. Now you have to find a suitable form for $1/\log^2$, which brings back the problem to finding a form for $1/\log^n$...

Comment: @VarunVejalla: Thanks, corrected.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3230893/221811